# I want blue color on top of bar using echarts

Tags: echarts

How to show border only at the top of the bar, like showing in the photo. The below code works but its showing border on all sides. I'm using echarts

[image]

```
   type: 'bar',
      itemStyle: {
        normal: {
          barBorderRadius: 0,
          borderColor: "rgba(0,170,255,0.8)",   
          borderWidth: [1],
          color: {
            type: 'linear',
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1,
            colorStops: [
              // dark blue dbf3ff (light) 00acff (dark)
              { offset: 0, color: '#dbf3ff' },
              // light blue
              { offset: 1, color: 'rgba(0, 172, 255, 0)' },
            ],
          }}},
```

Answer (score 5):

Echarts has no styles to control each border for the bar. For achieve desired you can make second series below and join it to first with stack and don't forget to hide tooltip. Look at example:

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
  var option = {
    tooltip: {},
    animation: false,
    xAxis: {
      data: ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6"]
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
        name: 'Series',
        stack: 'yes',
        type: 'bar',
        color: {
            type: 'linear',
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1,
            colorStops: [
              { offset: 0, color: '#dbf3ff' },
              { offset: 1, color: 'rgba(0, 172, 255, 0)' },
            ],
          },
        data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
      },
      {
        name: 'topBorder',
        stack: 'yes',
        type: 'bar',
        color: '#00acff',
        data: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        tooltip: { show: false }
      }
    ]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Its works 80% but this is not I was searching as it has some issues on the time of loading

Comment: Nobody knows what you were looking for because you did not tell about it. My solution is covered the question “I want blue color on top of bar using echarts”. The next comment of yours also does not describe the next problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### I found another solution with echarts ! tested with [react-native-echarts](https://wuba.github.io/react-native-echarts/)

> referred to @Sergey Fedorov's answer and this echarts example [custom-profit](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=custom-profit)
>
> ---
>
> also can control top border ***height*** such as really 1dp

#### image preview

[image]

#### key code is ***renderItem*** with ***custom*** type

```
const getSeriesConfigTopBorder = (name: string, datasetIndex: number) => {
  return {
    name: name,
    yAxisIndex: 0,
    type: 'custom',
    renderItem: (params: any, api: any) => {
      const typeValue = api.value(3);
      const yValue = api.value(2);
      const start = api.coord([api.value(0), yValue]);
      const size = api.size([api.value(1) - api.value(0), yValue]);
      let style: any = {}; // api.style() // https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/16514#issuecomment-1041032731
      switch (typeValue) {
        case PriceType.SHARP:
          style.fill = '#3bce76';
          break;
        case PriceType.PEAK:
          style.fill = '#ffc225';
          break;
        case PriceType.OFF_PEAK:
          style.fill = '#e50113';
          break;
        case PriceType.VALLEY:
          style.fill = '#2f6ce0';
          break;
      }
      style = {
        ...style,
        lineWidth: 0,
        stroke: 'transparent',
      };
      return {
        type: 'rect',
        shape: {
          x: start[0],
          y: start[1],
          width: size[0],
          height: 1,
        },
        style: style,
      };
    },
    // data: data,
    datasetIndex: datasetIndex,
    encode: {
      x: ['TIME_START', 'TIME_END'],
      y: 'VALUE',
      itemId: 'STATUS',
      tooltip: [],
      itemName: 'STATUS',
    },
  };
};
```